# What is default dependency scope in Gradle on Android?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In Gradle in Android Studio I noticed providing a dependency scope is optional. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

Notice the very last two libraries don't have a compile scope attached. I left it blank and I was still able to sync gradle. What is the default scope if nothing is specified here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope is actually a label for a given dependency configuration. It depends very much on the gradle plugins you are using (i.e.: java plugin or android plugin).
If you don't add any configuration label, it will be saved as an unlabeled dependency.
Most of the time if you need a `implementation` dependency and do not add the label, your build will break. If it doesn't break it could be because:

- You were not actually needing the dependency
- You are using a gradle plugin that handles nicely unlabeled dependencies
- Or (more probably), the dependency is already on your build cache or partial build and therefore the compiler is still able to find the classes, but will break if you clean the project.

Related documentation [on dependency configuration for gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:configurations)

Comment: yah i see what you mean. Gradle sync was successful but when i went to actually run the application then it says it cant find scope.  Its very odd the sync is successful though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small update to Logain's answer. `compile` is deprecated now. `implementation` can be used to replace it. 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management